# Insert sound in pascalABC

Tags: pascalabc.net

I am creating a simple pascalABC game that a ball bounces of a stick and the bonds off the window height and width and I have 2 questions.

**Question #1**

How can I insert a sound so like if the ball bounces off a sound is heard

**NOTE**: I got these errors:

> Unit 'MMSystem' not found
> Unit 'Windows' not found

**Question #2**

How could I add a delay like when the user lose a delay of X(s) is on
I try using function:

```
Delay(3000)
```

but then I got this error :

> Undefined name reference 'Delay'

I tried sleep function but even sleep is not getting me what I want since the game stops for the nb of seconds I specified and then "GAMEOVER" text is shown and hidden in less than a second